# create calculated member based on date for condition

Tags: ssas

I have a Date dimension that I would like to check current month and current year, and then display a different Measure depending on that evaluation.

example:
 MM - 04
 YY -2016

Calculated member determines current month then for months prior(1-3) it shows measure Qty Shipped. For current month and beyond(4-12) it shows measure Forecast. This logic is only working with current year.

Thanks.

```
IIF(([02 Dates].[MM].currentmember,[Measures].[Qty Shipped])<
            (
            STRTOMEMBER('[02 Dates].[MM].&['+format(now(),'yyyy')+']&['+format(now(),'MM')+']')
            ,[Measures].[Qty Shipped]),
            [Measures].[Qty Shipped], 
            [Measures].[Current Forecast])
```

Seems to do the Current Month on correctly, but doesn't move qty shipped to months 1-3.
Thanks

Does this logic look correct.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: please post your code ,it will be useful to handle your question

Comment: Why don't you simply get both measures, and only look at the one you want based on the date?

Comment: Echoing the other comments: if you post the code that works for current year, and the (non-working) code for current month, it'll be much easier to help.

Comment: I have added the code Thanks

Comment: Any suggestions and examples on how to make this work?